# NestJS Can't reslove dependencies of service mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

My Nest Application is throwing the following error when running

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService (?, UserProfileModel). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the AuthModule context. +3ms
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService (?, UserProfileModel). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the AuthModule context.
    at Injector.lookupComponentInExports (PATH\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:183:19)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

For context, I'm trying to set up a connection with MongoDB Atlas using Mongoose. The only answer I found to this issue was to add `TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserModel])` to the module imports. However, I don't think that's relevant here because mongoose already does that. Here are the code snippets

Auth Module TS

```
 imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{name: 'User', schema: UserModelSchema}, {name: 'UserProfile', schema: UserProfileModelSchema}])],
    controllers: [AuthController],
    providers: [UserService],
```

App Module TS

```
  imports: [AuthModule, MongooseModule.forRoot(config.dbServer)],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
```

Auth Service TS

```
constructor(@InjectModel('Users')private readonly users: Model<UserModel>,
     @InjectModel('UserProfile') private readonly userProfile: Model<UserProfileModel>){
    }
```

Help Much Appreciated

Answer (score 3):

In your imports `'User'` is singular:

```
{name: 'User', schema: UserModelSchema}
        ^^^^
```

and in your constructor `'Users'` is plural:

```
@InjectModel('Users')
              ^^^^^
```

Should be the same.